# How can I stop the repetition of the same element in a loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a problem in python with my loop for.

I have a repetition of the same element and I don't know why.

Here it's my code :

```
x=0
liste=[]
for x in range(len(valeur)):
    for i in range(x+1,len(valeur)):
        ed = nltk.edit_distance(valeur[x],valeur[i])
        dico={"titre":valeur[x],"titre_compare":valeur[i], "distance":ed}
        a=((dico["titre"],(dico["titre_compare"]),(dico["distance"])))

        for z in range (len(a)):
            if a[2]<6 and a[0] != ' None ' and a[1] != ' None ' and a[2] != ' None ' :

                print(a)
```

My code works perfectly but I don't understand why I got this :

```
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
```

and not only this :

```
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
```

I tried to search and I discovered it :

When I put this for example :

```
a=((dico["titre"],"&&",(dico["titre_compare"]),"&&",(dico["distance"])))
```

It returns 5 times

```
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
(' K. Hardono ', ' Cardon. ', 5)
```

So I know that my repetition of the same element provide of my number element of my dictionary in python but I don't know how I can have only 1 element and not a repetition.

Thanks if you can help me

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I try to compare 2 words and their distance, and I put my code to do it.  I try to search words with a distance <5  to know if they are duplicate element in my long database.

Comment: What kind of distance? What would the input be for the code you shared, what is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like the tuple `a` that you are making has a length of 3, right?

So when you make your next for loop with `z`, `z` will take on the values of [0, 1, 2] during the loop.  That loop does the same thing each time (no dependency on `z`) so it will print `a` 3 times.

Look again at your loop with `z` and think about what you are trying to do.  Also where you define your tuple `a` the parenthesis are a bit out of whack...

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I try to browse my dico  and recuperate the words when distance is <5  but I knew where is the error and why it put me this like result, but I don't know how I can correct it